# Write logger file to directory using python logger

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to create a log file in specific directory using python logger.but I am getting invalid argument error.

```
import logging
import time

path='c:\\users\\documents\\'
hndlr=logging.FileHandler(os.path.join(path,time.strftime('log_'+'%Y-%m-%d'+'.log')))
```

When I execute the above, I am getting below error.

`OSERROR: invalid argument: 'C:\\users\\documents\\log_2021-09-20.log`'

Kindly let me know how to set a path while logging in python.

Thank you.

Comment: Could it be a problem with the `'C:\\users\\documents'` folder? You can only create a file into an existing an writeable directory. And on my system, this one does not exists...

Comment: I just gave it as a sample folder... The actual folder that I use exists. Is it a problem if there is a space in foler structure like below
C:\\users\\xyz\\documents\\test folder\\log. I am wondering if the space between test and folder might create issue?

Comment: A space should cause no harm. Did you twice control that the path contains no typo (`dir path` in a cmd window is a handy trick)?

Comment: Yes. Path is correct and it exists.. I am trying to exeucte from IDE spyder. Could that be an issue?

Comment: Hmm... is the message you show the **exact** error message? Could you show the full message including the stack strace?

Comment: I figured it out.. there was an issue with path. Thank you.